# How to stop jQuery code block execution after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery. Every time i am clicking the div associated with class="panda", it is executing the following code block. But i want it to execute only first time i click on that div.
This is my code-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.panda').click(function(){
$('.panda').sprite({fps: 10, no_of_frames: 4});
})

})
```

Hope you guys will help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.panda').one('click', function(){
        $('.panda').sprite({fps: 10, no_of_frames: 4});
    });
});
```

---

From jQuery documentation:

> **`one():`** Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.